# mysql_escape_string in php

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Just a quick query really, In my PHP file, I have variables coming from my HTML form, like so:

```
$companyName = mysql_escape_string($_POST['compName']);
$AddLine1 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['add']);
$AddLine2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['add1']);            
$AddLine3 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['add2']);
```

Throughout this script, I do a few select, insert statements with mysql. What I'm wondering is, is it okay to just use the mysql_escape_string once like above, or do I need to do it every time I use the variable?

Probably a really simple (or silly) question but I said I'd ask anyway.

Comment: You can reuse your `$companyName`, `$AddLine1`, `$AddLine2` etc. variables again further down your script, as those hold the escape user input. is this what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once is sufficient, `$AddLine1-3` now holds "Safe" values

Comment: That's great, thank you. I will accept this as the correct answer once I'm able to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is enough to do it once. Plus, if `$_POST['val']` should be integer, you can do `(int) $_POST['val']` and it will be totally safe too.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out PHP.NET.  They state that:

```
mysql_escape_string
```

has been deprecated and should be replaced with :

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

Reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: @Maekins, thanks for that, I will check it out. Seems to be working fine so far anyway but good to know for the future!

Answer (score 0):

You you working with standart php functions so you can use mysql_escape_string only then you need work with database queries.